# Finding patterns in php array

Tags: php, arrays, search, find

For example:

main array is: `array(0 => 'A', 1 => 'A', 2 => 'B', 3 => 'B', 4 => 'B');`

pattern is: `array('A', 'B');`

expected answer: `array( array(0, 2), array(1, 3) )`

***one more example:***

main array `array(0 => 'F', 5 => 'G', 78 => 'R', 2 => 'D');`

pattern `array('G', 'R', 'F');`

expected answer: `array(array(5, 78, 0))`

How can I find all occurrences of pattern in array?

Comment: What does `array(0, 2)` and `array(1, 3)` mean?

Comment: @Rocket I think it is makes more sense to think of it as array( 'A' => array( 0, 2 ), 'B' => array( 1, 3 ) )

Comment: @Rocket it's ids of pattern matched elements. In example there is two matched pairs -> (0,2) (1,3)

Comment: @Yekver: So for `array(0, 2)`. The `0` is the index of `A` in the pattern array. and `2` is the number of `A`s in the main array?

Comment: @Rocket: nope, for `array(0, 2)` the `0` is the index of `A` in the main array, and `2` is the index of `B` in the main array

Comment: @Yekver: Then what is `array(1,3)`?  I'm not completely seeing what exactly you expected answer is supposed to mean.  I thought it was the count of `A`s and `B`s (which happen to be 2 and 3).

Comment: @Rocket I've updated the question hope it's clear now to understand what I mean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an function that uses recursion.

```
function array_pattern($array, $pattern){
    $ret = array(array());
    $found = true;
    foreach($pattern as $val){
        $x = array_search($val, $array);
        if($x === FALSE){
            $found = FALSE;
            break;
        }
        unset($array[$x]);
        $ret[0][] = $x;
    }
    return $found ? array_merge($ret, array_pattern($array, $pattern)) : array();
}
```

Call it like this:

```
$a = array_pattern(array(0 => 'A', 1 => 'A', 2 => 'B', 3 => 'B', 4 => 'B'), array('A', 'B'));
$b = array_pattern(array(0 => 'F', 5 => 'G', 78 => 'R', 2 => 'D'), array('G', 'R', 'F'));
```

DEMO: http://codepad.org/JCdsAMGk

Answer (score 0):

I didn't test the following code, but it may give you ideas.

```
$arr = array(0 => 'A', 1 => 'A', 2 => 'B', 3 => 'B', 4 => 'B');
$test = array('G', 'R', 'F');

$count = 0;
$count2 = 0; 
for($i=0;$i<count($arr);$++){
    $pass= true;
    if(count($test)+$count <= count($arr)){
        for($k=0;$k<count($test);$k++){
            if($arr[k+i]!=$test[k]){
                  $pass = false;
            }
        }
    }else{
       $pass = false;
    }

     if($pass){
       $output[$count2] = $i;
       $count2++;
     }


}
```